# Custom path completion in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, tab-completion

I want to write a bash_completion script for my own file system. I have client program which sends queries to some DB.

example:

```
my_prog --ls db_name:/foo/bar/
```

this command writes to stdout list of files in `db_name:/foo/bar` folder.

I want to enable autocompletion for this. So when i press tab it shows list of options.

```
my_prog --ls db_name:/foo/bar/<tab>
```

but in this case when I press tab and there is single option it replaces the current entered path, so I'm getting this:

```
$ my_prog --ls db_name:/foo/bar/<tab>
$ my_prog --ls file
```

But I want the match to be added to end of entered path.

Here is my completion function:

```
__complete_path()
{
    COMPREPLY=()

    if [[ ${1} == "" ]]
    then
        COMPREPLY=( "/" )
        compopt -o nospace
        return
    fi

    base=${1##*/}
    dir=${1%/*}

    options="my_prog --ls ${db}:${dir}"
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${options}" -- ${base} ) )

    compopt -o nospace
}
```

Comment: What is `${db}`??

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread while trying something similar. 
[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55520/create-bash-completion-script-to-autocomplete-paths-after-is-equal-sign) stackexchange post helped me in putting the autocomplete function below together. It isn't quite as the "normal" autocompletion as the full paths are shown, but otherwise you may find it useful.

```
_complete_func()
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]; then
    opts="some options for the program"
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
    elif [ $COMP_CWORD -ge 2 ]; then
    local files=("${cur}"*)
        COMPREPLY=( "${files[@]}")
fi
}
complete -o nospace -F complete_func command_to_autocomplete
```